# Record field doesn't have default value

Tags: oracle, plsql, record, varray

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE
 TYPE rt_someDetails IS RECORD(
    deny_discount           VARCHAR2(4) DEFAULT 'NO');
 TYPE someDetails_va IS VARRAY(2) OF rt_someDetails;

 l_someDetails_va someDetails_va;
 l_rt_someDetails rt_someDetails;
BEGIN
 l_someDetails_va := someDetails_va();
 l_someDetails_va.EXTEND;

 -- when in varray, the default value doesn't show up
 dbms_output.put_line('From array:: ' || l_someDetails_va(1).deny_discount);

 -- However, when outside of varray, it works properly
 dbms_output.put_line('Directly from record var:: ' || l_rt_someDetails.deny_discount);
END;
```

Why doesn't the default value of `deny_discount` show up when read from the record in varray?

Comment: extending doesn't populate the array, it simply allocates space for future inserts

Comment: So I should create a record, insert it into the varray and THEN try to access the field. Answer the question so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending doesn't populate the array per say, it simply allocates space for future inserts (think NULL elements)

Try creating a record and inserting into the array.  Simply extending won't show anything.